# FQL - EVENT table

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

When using the the "Graph API Explorer":

```sql
SELECT name FROM event
WHERE eid IN (
    SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 207255995711
)
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

everything is fine & works. But when I try to run the `fql-query` on my server, it returns an empty Array.

Only 50% of the UIDs don't work. When I use `155326044518189` instead of the `207255995711`, everything works fine.

Both are set on OPEN / PUBLIC. But only works in the "Graph API Explorer" 100%
Steps to reproduce, try to get some output with this piece of code:

```php
<?php

require 'facebook_lib/facebook.php';
require 'facebook_lib/config.php';

try {


$fql = "SELECT name FROM event
WHERE eid IN (
SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 207255995711
)
ORDER BY start_time DESC";


$param = array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => $fql,
'callback' => ''
);

$fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}

foreach($fqlResult as $keys => $values):

echo $values['name'];
echo '<br>';

endforeach;

?>
```

http://lab.daniel-walter.com/facebook2/facebook.php

Comment: Have you got the user_events permission for your users? Are they actually attending any upcoming events? I only have two events in my list when i check with the correct permissions, one for last week and one in 2038

Comment: for "public events" you dont need any permission -am i right ?

Comment: http://lab.daniel-walter.com/facebook2/facebook.php